# VBA clear cell C if I clear cell B

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and have been trying to get this to work for the last few days.
I have 2 columns.

B-student
C-date

What I want is when a student comes in and puts their initials in column B then it fills in the date in column C in that row.

Now if i delete the students initials I want it to clear the C cell also for that row.

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Training")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim StaffRange As Range
Set StaffRange = ws.Range("B5:B40")
Dim StaffTime As Range

' If they put in initials in StaffRange then proceed
If Not Intersect(Target, StaffRange) Is Nothing Then
Set StaffTime = ws.Range("C" & Target.Row)
If StaffTime.Value <> "" Then Exit Sub 'if there is already a date then exit
StaffTime.Value = Now     ' put in the date time
    
'now if they clear StaffRange then clear StaffTime
ElseIf Intersect(Target, StaffRange) Is Nothing Then
Set StaffTime = ws.Range("C" & Target.Row)
StaffTime.ClearContents     ' make blank

End If

End Sub
```

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: What is the problem you're having?  Does your code not work?  What does it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem, just change references to `.Value = ""` to `.clear`.

As well, you need to add a reference to the sheet you are working within, otherwise, your reference to `Range` can "confuse" the macro.

---

Explanation

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)  ' defines the workbook you are working in. You could change "ThisWorkbook" to the actual workbook name, but note that any changes to the workbook name (such as auto recover) will require you to modify this variable.
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' defines the worksheet within the workbook defined above.
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim StaffRange As Range
    Dim StaffTime As Range
    Dim TrainerRange As Range
    Dim TrainerTime As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name) 
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set StaffRange = ws.Range("B5:B40")
    Set TrainerRange = ws.Range("D5:D40")
    
    ' If they put in initials in StaffRange then procede with entering the date stamp
    If Not Intersect(Target, StaffRange) Is Nothing Then
    Set StaffTime = ws.Range("C" & Target.Row)
    If StaffTime.Value <> "" Then Exit Sub 'if there is already a date in field do not update and exit
    StaffTime.Value = Now     ' put in the date time
    
    ' now if they clear StaffRange then clear StaffTime
    ' cell cleared
    ElseIf Intersect(Target, StaffRange) Is Nothing Then
    Set StaffTime = ws.Range("C" & Target.Row)
    ' If StaffTime.Value = "" Then Exit Sub    ' if it is already clear exit
    StaffTime.clear     ' make blank
    
    ' If they put in initials in TrainerRange then procede with entering the date stamp
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, TrainerRange) Is Nothing Then
    Set TrainerTime = ws.Range("E" & Target.Row)
    If TrainerTime.Value <> "" Then Exit Sub
    TrainerTime.Value = Now
    
    ' now if they clear TrainerRange then clear TrainerTime
    ' cell cleared
    ElseIf Intersect(Target, TrainerRange) Is Nothing Then
    clearing
    Set StaffTime = ws.Range("E" & Target.Row)
    ' If StaffTime.Value = "" Then Exit Sub    ' if it is already clear exit
    StaffTime.clear     ' make blank
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Better to just use `Me` inside the worksheet code module, if you want to refer explicitly to that sheet.  However, the default worksheet for Range/Cells/etc in a sheet module is that sheet, not the ActiveSheet, so you don't really need to be explicit...

Comment: I'm not familiar outside of using it for forms. @TimWilliams, want to edit my answer with your suggestion?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of editing other people's answers...

Comment: @Mech I tried it and it did not work,  I simplified my code to only look at column B&C and updated it with what you mentioned.  It is still not working.

Comment: @tim-williams I cleaned up my code a bit and added what Mech suggested.  I also added more details to my question as you asked.  It is still not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim b As Range, c As Range, rng As Range
    'updates in range of interest?
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("B5:B40"), Target)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'nothing to process...
    
    For Each b In rng.Cells
        Set c = b.Offset(0, 1)
        If Len(b.Value) > 0 Then
            If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then c.Value = Now 'value entered: add time
        Else
            c.ClearContents                        'value cleared: clear time
        End If
    Next b
    
End Sub
```

Comment: that worked great.  Can this be set to look at D5:D40 and do the same also?

Comment: `Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("B5:B40,D5:D40"), Target)`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.  Thank you both for your code.  I learned from both and came up with this.

If it can be cleaned up I would appreciate any pointers.

Thanks again

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim b As Range, c As Range, d As Range, e As Range, rngb As Range, rngd As Range
    'updates in range of interest?
Set rngb = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("B5:B40"), Target)
Set rngd = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("D5:D40"), Target)

If Not rngb Is Nothing Then
For Each b In rngb.Cells
    Set c = b.Offset(0, 1)
    If Len(b.Value) > 0 Then
        If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then c.Value = Now 'value entered: add time
    Else
        c.ClearContents                        'value cleared: clear time
    End If
Next b
End If

If Not rngd Is Nothing Then
For Each d In rngd.Cells
    Set e = d.Offset(0, 1)
    If Len(d.Value) > 0 Then
        If Len(e.Value) = 0 Then e.Value = Now 'value entered: add time
    Else
        e.ClearContents                        'value cleared: clear time
    End If
Next d
End If

End Sub
```